# Unable to Configure MQTT Client ID using Adafruit MQTT Library

Tags: adafruit, mqtt

I am utilizing the MQTT library that Adafruit has created, located [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library), and the library itself works wonderfully - however I am finding myself unable to edit the Client ID or configure the PINGRESP. The code that I am currently using can be seen below -

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, "10.116.10.191", 1883);
```

When the client connects to the MQTT Broker the client ID turns into a random string of letters, numbers, and symbols, as seen below -

```
1534023607: Client ]7llG5K6J4=^tPHJHqgTUFc<Ep^m3vJ`4vSL2oB<cO[^_chw[GBp]v3smagpOqWS has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1534023608: New connection from 10.116.7.21 on port 1883.
1534023608: New client connected from 10.116.7.21 as ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu (c1, k300).
1534023608: Sending CONNACK to ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu (0)
1534023608: Received SUBSCRIBE from ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu
1534023608:     quantity (QoS 0)
1534023608: ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu 0 quantity
1534023608: Sending SUBACK to ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu
```

After a duration of time has passed the client exceeds the time out and disconnects.. Any advice on overcoming this obstacle would be greatly appreciated. I've tried the following for changing the ClientID, per the client constructor to the MQTT broker -

```
Adafruit_MQTT_Client(Client *client, const char *server, uint16_t port,
   const char *cid, const char *user, const char *pass):
```

---

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, "10.116.10.191", 1883, "Rear-Controller");
```

This was the result of adding the clientID, ("Rear-Controller"), after the MQTT Broker port # -

```
 New client connected from 10.116.7.21 as GFONMktFXFSG1rARE@JWCRv@P^XwLifdo<rCg]YFs4Ndf_>2_XIsjFsAtS08Cf\: (c1, k300, uRear-Controller)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Client ID is expected to be stored in flash memory (it is read using `pgm_read_byte`). However, on the Arduino, unless told otherwise it first copies the string literal into RAM.  That means that the function is getting the address of the string in RAM, not in flash, and using it as if it were the address in flash, and that gets gibberish.

You need to force it to be in flash by creating a PROGMEM string:

```
const char clientid[] PROGMEM = "clientfoo";
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, "10.116.10.191", 1883, clientid);
```

Comment: I was met with this error: 
No matching function for call to 'Adafruit_MQTT_Client::Adafruit_MQTT_Client(WiFiClient*, const char [14], int, const __FlashStringHelper*)'

Comment: Not having your code to test I did wonder if that may happen. You may need to cast it to a const char * as well. Or have it separate as PROGMEM.

Comment: I converted it to a const char and it successfully compiled, however it still had the gibberish.. That only seems to effect - "(c1, k300, uRear-Controller)"

Comment: @HobarGJ See my edit. That should work.

Comment: While that did successfully compile, I am still getting the string of gibberish when connecting to the MQTT Broker. The end, "(c1, k300, uRear-Controller)", is correct and reflects the changes though. Would uploading more of my code be any easier for you?

Comment: I'd suggest switching to PubSubClient instead. It works.

Comment: @HobarGJ i agree with Majenko the [MQTT-API][1] said "If the MQTT library requires that you set a client ID then use a unique value like a random GUID.  Most MQTT libraries handle setting the client ID to a random value automatically though." i cannot see your library can require to set client ID, i also using PubSubClient, that works to me sir.


  [1]: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io/mqtt-api